# Hide lightbox form on close; using colorbox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using colorbox.js, I am opening a form in a lightbox when the user clicks on the corresponding link. Right now, when the user visits the page the form is hidden but when the they click on the link the form is viewable in the lightbox. When the close the lightbox out, the form is then visible on the actual page. I would like for the form to be hidden on the page when the user exits the lightbox. Here is my script so far http://jsfiddle.net/j9ths/ :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").hide();

        $("#link_to_form").click(function() {
            $("#myForm").show();
        });

        $("#link_to_form").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#myForm" });

        $("#cboxClose").click(function() {
            $("#myForm").hide();
        });
 });
```

The div id of #cboxClose is the "x" button on the lightbox.

Comment: can you give more code? probably a jsfiddle might really help us help you!

Comment: Ok I added a link to jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write onClose callback as you can see [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).

```
    $("#link_to_form").colorbox({
        width: "50%",
        inline: true,
        href: "#myForm",
        onclose: function() {
             $("#myForm").hide();
        }
    });

$("#cboxClose").on('click', function() {
    $("#link_to_form").colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: I am still seeing the form after closing out of the lightbox. Any ideas?

Comment: After hide, alert something and see if it's being called.

Comment: No, I don't think it is being called. Would there be another way to accomplish this instead of using "onclose"?

Comment: Ok, your answer helped a lot. I modified the code a little and got everything working. Thanks!